# Checking/ Referencing Empty Array Values (Google App Script)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that does some simple cell referencing and math for monthly travel for work. I have a function that reads the values in column A (which are attained by the WEEKDAY() formula on the sheet. It blacks out the whole row if it is a Saturday(value 5) or Sunday(value 6). I need it to format the weekdays a certain way (values 0-4) and, only if the date cell in that row is blank, to reformat that row back to the standard blank. **How do I search through an array (you can see how I created it) and find an empty value in that array**? I will copy-paste an example log of the array values (notice the periodic [])

```
function weekendClean() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:A33")
  var value = range.getValues()
  var sheetCheckRange = sheet.getRange(2,2)
  var sheetCheck = sheetCheckRange.getValue()
  if (sheetCheck == "Date") {
    for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      if (value[i] == 5 || value[i] == 6) {
        var row = sheet.getRange((i + 3), 1, 1, 11)
        var cell = sheet.getRange((i + 3), 3)
        row.setBackground("Black")
        row.setBorder(true, null, true, null, null, null)
        //top, left, bottom, right, vertical, horizontal
        cell.setValue("W")
      } if (value[i] == 0 || value[i] == 1 || value[i] == 2 || value[i] == 3 || value[i] == 4) {
        var section1 = sheet.getRange((i+3), 2, 1, 5)
        var section2 = sheet.getRange((i+3), 8, 1, 3)
        section1.setBackground("white")
        section2.setBackground("white")
        section1.setBorder(false, null, false, null, null, false)
        section2.setBorder(false, null, false, null, null, false)
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Also, feel free to clean up that code with explanation (especially for the bit that reads what to do for the weekdays)

```
[15-09-01 17:54:04:051 PDT] [[1.0], [2.0], [], [4.0], [5.0], [6.0],
[0.0], [1.0], [], [3.0], [4.0], [5.0], [], [], [1.0], [], [3.0],
[4.0], [5.0], [6.0], [0.0], [1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [], [5.0], [6.0],
[0.0], [1.0], [2.0], []]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked around the issue of finding which spot in the array was empty and rather set up a variable to reference each cell in the loop and check if it itself was blank. If it saw that it was, it performed the code block. Example below.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:A33")
  var value = range.getValues()
  var sheetCheckRange = sheet.getRange(2,2)
  var sheetCheck = sheetCheckRange.getValue()
  if (sheetCheck == "Date") {
    for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      var row = sheet.getRange((i + 3), 1, 1, 11)
      var sessionCell = sheet.getRange((i + 3), 3)
      var dateCell = sheet.getRange((i+3), 2)
      var section1 = sheet.getRange((i+3), 2, 1, 5)
      var section2 = sheet.getRange((i+3), 8, 1, 3)
      if (value[i] == 5 || value[i] == 6) {
        row.setBackground("Black")
        row.setBorder(true, null, true, null, null, null)
        //top, left, bottom, right, vertical, horizontal
        sessionCell.setValue("W")
      } if (value[i] == 0 || value[i] == 1 || value[i] == 2 || value[i] == 3 || value[i] == 4) {
        section1.setBackground("white")
        section2.setBackground("white")
        section1.setBorder(false, null, false, null, null, false)
        section2.setBorder(false, null, false, null, null, false)
      } if (dateCell.isBlank()) {
        section1.setBackground("white")
        section2.setBackground("white")
        section1.setBorder(false, null, false, null, null, false)
        section2.setBorder(false, null, false, null, null, false)
        sessionCell.setValue("")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also worked around needing a separate trigger by renaming the function to
    function onEdit()
This also makes it much easier to copy the spreadsheet for sharing within the company. With the function named 'onEdit()', there's no need for authorization and setup of triggers by each user.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about `isBlank`.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you would retrieve an empty array in your situation :

```
var x = [[1.0], [2.0], [], [4.0], [5.0], [6.0], [0.0], [1.0], [], [3.0], [4.0], [5.0], [], [], [1.0], [], [3.0], [4.0], [5.0], [6.0], [0.0], [1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [], [5.0], [6.0], [0.0], [1.0], [2.0], []];

function myFunction(x) {
 for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i ++) {

  if(x[i].length == 0){
    // array is empty 
    Logger.log('empty'); 
   } else {
    //array not empty
    Logger.log('not empty');
  }

 }
}
```

I also noticed that the ";" is missing from your statements. Your script runs as it is ?

Cheers

Comment: Yes! That makes so much sense. I didn't think about reading the length of each data value instead of just checking if it was there. Thank you!

Comment: And yes, Google Apps Script isn't very picky about it's ';' use. I realize it's sloppy coding and if I were sending this out for other people's use I'd clean it up. I just needed to get something in place for work and I didn't take the time to clean it up. Thank you though!

Comment: This didn't work for me...it never recognized the condition.

    if (value[i].length === 0) {
            var section1 = sheet.getRange((i+3), 2, 1, 5)
            var section2 = sheet.getRange((i+3), 8, 1, 3)
            var cell = sheet.getRange((i+3), 3)
            section1.setBackground("white")
            section2.setBackground("white")
            section1.setBorder(false, null, false, null, null, false)
            section2.setBorder(false, null, false, null, null, false)
            Logger.log("Empty")

Comment: Try to correct your `value[i].length ===  0`; there seems to be one too many '='.

Answer (score 0):

The [ArrayLib library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library) would be able to do this for you, it makes the process of dealing with 2D arrays much simpler. For this, you'd want the IndexOf function, and use -1 to search through all columns.

Comment: I'll look into this, the answer below suggested reading the length of each value and the empty ones would have length 0. I'm going to try that before needing to pull in another service. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. I need to locate all empty cells so that it knows exactly which ones to clear and reformat back to the basic clean version (done programatically).

Answer (score 0):

Use a comparison to **null**

```
var x = [[1.0], [2.0], [], [4.0], [5.0], [6.0], [0.0], [1.0], [], [3.0], [4.0], [5.0], [], [], [1.0], [], [3.0], [4.0], [5.0], [6.0], [0.0], [1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [], [5.0], [6.0], [0.0], [1.0], [2.0], []];

function myFunction(x) {
 for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i ++) {

  if(x[i] == null){
    // array is empty 
    Logger.log('empty'); 
   } else {
    //array not empty
    Logger.log('not empty');
  }

 }
}
```