# Google app script IF condition not matching 0, empty and null

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have issues with Google app script IF condition.
Problem i am facing its not returning value TRUE rather going to next/ Else statements.
Code i am having:

```
const numberOfRowsToUpdate = deliveryDate.length;

// For each item making the for loop to work
for (i=0 ; i < numberOfRowsToUpdate;i++) {
    debugger;
  var dp = depositAmount[i];
  if(dp!==""|| dp!==0 || dp !==null || dp!==isblank())
   { .... <statements>
   }
}
```

I want to check whether particular cell of the array is empty / zero / returning null value.

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What if `dp` is undefined?

Comment: What are you receiving if you log the `dp` variable?

Answer (score 0):

#### SUGGESTION

I have used a similar script I'm using for a spreadsheet in which I need to search through every row for some data, but obviously adpating it to your case, and since I don't have your full code (and still can't comment asking for more info due to my recent joining in SO), I had to simplify it, in hope it will work for you.

What I did was use your incrementing `i` index from the `for` loop and use it to scan every row, while adjusting it to fit your array index, because we can't have `i = 0` as a row index, and it would skip the first value on the array if left as `i = 1`).

#### SCRIPT

```
function test(){

const n = 6;
var depositAmount = [7,2,0,2,0,8];

// For each item making the for loop to work
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
Logger.log(ss.getName());
for (var i=1 ; i <= n ;i++) {
    debugger;
    ss.getRange("A"+i).setValue(1);
  var dp = depositAmount[i-1];
  Logger.log(dp)
  if(dp != "" || dp != 0 /*|| dp != null || dp != isblank()*/)
   {
     ss.getRange("B"+i).setValue(dp);
   }
   else 
   {
     ss.getRange("C"+i).setValue("VOID")
     Logger.log(i-1+"th index of array is "+ss.getRange("C"+i).getValue());
   }
}

};
```

#### RESULTS

After running it with the four original conditions you used, i didn't get the expected result, as you must have, leading to this:

[image: this].

While studying your original code, I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) about the differences between `==` and `===`, as well as `!=` and `!==`.

So *before* I used this in our favor, I tried the old trial and error method, using only one condition at a time, and then stacking them up. Not only I managed to find out the `!==` operator didn't work properly for this case, but also the comparison with `null` and the `isblank()` function (at least in my case, because i haven't defined it, and I'm not sure it is a built-in function) also don't work with either operator.

Therefore, using the `!=` operator helps you better than the strict `!==`.
The result of the final script is that:

[image: that].

#### NOTES

I also tried using a null value within the array (`[7,2,0,2,,8]`), but it would always break away from the loop, never scanning the whole array, and I don't know how to circle that.

Here is the Execution Log for this script:

[image: LOG]

#### EDIT

While fooling around, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343116/checking-referencing-empty-array-values-google-app-script) and the answer by [Etienne de Villers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5104345/etienne-de-villers) might be even faster to apply, or at least more useful for your purposes.